# Indexing for key which belongs to Primary key of other table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a two table as  table as

```
@Entity
 @Table(name = "product", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"product_idn"}))
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 21409635044L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String product_idn;
}
```

another table as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "storage")
public class Storage implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -67165579239L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Product product;
}
```

Now I am fetching record from **storage** table. Should create a index (Non-Unique)on **product_id** of storage table? I have to fetch storages count per on product/ featching storages based on product.

Answer (score 0):

Just add @Index annoation like below and it should work fine.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "storage", indexes = @Index(columnList = "product_id",name = "storage_productId_index"))
public class Storage implements Serializable
```